# Detailed soln git revert command

Tags: git

if delete a fie in git then revert it's changeset then view list of files how deleted file is present in that location?

to know About deleted file storage

Comment: If you delete a file, then revert, isn't it logical that the deleted file reappears?

Answer (score 1):

When working with git it is important to understand the underlying model: [Each commit is a snapshot of the repository](https://github.blog/2020-12-17-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs/) and all the snapshots are kept. So if you revert a delete, git simply restores the files out of the snapshot directly before the deletion.

This behaviour can sometimes become a problem when you accidentally committed sensitive information (like a password). Simply deleting the file will not remove the password from the repository as anyone with access to the repository could just restore the password from that commit.